# How to Create a View of a Particular Content Type when there are Mulitple Content Types?

Tags: content-type, library, view

Salvete!  I have a forms-library with two content-types that appear in the "New Document" menu.  How can I create a view and choose which content-type to use?

Let me explain.  I have two content-types:  "custom" and "form".
"Form" only shows the filename.
"Custom" shows fields from inside the form.

Now, I want "custom view" to work just for the "custom" content-type, and "form" to just work for the "form" content-type.

Is there a way to specify which content-type is used by each view?

Comment: Are you talking about the forms of the list that are displayed when you view list item, create list item, or modify list item?

Comment: Yes. I can choose between two "new" items.  I want to be able to create a view for one form and another view for the other form.

Answer (score 1):

BGM,

> i’m assuming you are talking about Data Views in SP designer 2010.
>   there seams to be a few solutions out there, one creating a SOAP
>   service, which is painful. i have also created a view in the browser,
>   filtered by content type – then edited the view in SP designer – this
>   then pre-populates the filter with the “contentType” field name – BUT
>   if you make any changes to the view (or delete the wrong one) your in
>   trouble… the other option that has worked for me is to use sharepoint
>   designer to insert a data view on your document library, add a filter
>   (any will be fine. then look at the code for data view, and you should
>   see the “query” tags.
>
> ```
> <Query> <Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name=”FieldName”/> <Value Type=”Computed”>MyVal</Value> </Eq> </Where>
> </Query>
> ```
>
> replace FieldName with “ContentType” and the content type
>   will appear in the filter. it’s a bit of a hack – but seams to have
>   the least side effects for me.

SOURCE: [SharePoint Group by or Filter by Content Type](http://www.petestilgoe.com/2010/10/sharepoint-2010-group-by-content-type-view-by-content-type/), see the first comment!

Comment: No, I haven't used SP Designer for any of this, yet.  That solution is "hacky" - that is, I would have to remember that it was done, and how to do it again should I edit the views, no?  It would be easy for someone to mess it up.  Interesting approach however.